# How to pass data between two dialogs in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog in mfc and my main view. The view starts a new dialog which takes in two int values and I want to return these values to my view. I know I have to do something with dodataexchange and here is the code from my dialog:

```
void MapCreator::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX){    

    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    CString stringColumn; 
    CString stringRow; 

    CWnd* dialog = GetDlgItem(columns);
    dialog->GetWindowText(stringColumn);

    dialog = GetDlgItem(rows);
    dialog->GetWindowText(stringRow);

    int numColumn = _wtoi(stringColumn);
    int numRow = _wtoi(stringRow);

    DDX_Text(pDX, columns, numColumn);
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, numColumn, 1, 50); 
    DDX_Text(pDX, rows, numRow);
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, numRow, 1, 50); 

}
```

Now how can I access theses values in view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you sync data and view in MFC is something like this:

Assume you have a edit box with resource id **IDC_MY_EDITBOX** and you want to bind it to a CString object. Changes to CString should reflect in the edit box and changes to your string object should update your UI. For this example lets call your CString object a member variable 
**mEditBoxString**

```
class MapCreator : public CDialog
{
//Everything else omitted for brevity
CString mEditBoxString; 
};
```

Your DoDataExchange should look something like

```
void MapCreator ::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_MY_EDITBOX, mEditBoxString);
}
```

This has established a two way binding between the variable and the view ( **The edit box** )

If you change the mEditBoxString in code and want it to reflect in UI. Somehow DoDataExchange needs to be invoked. You do it by calling **[CWnd::UpdateData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** which in your case will be a base class method.

If you pass **FALSE** to the UpdateData it means the UI will be updated with any changes that you did with mEditBoxString.

If you pass **TRUE** to the UpdateData it means mEditBoxString variable will be updated from the UI. So if the user has indeed edited the box the new value will be stored in **mEditBoxString**

Lets say you also have a button (say **LOAD**) in your dialog that is wired to this function

```
void CMapCreatorDlg::OnLoadClicked()
{
    //Do you heavy loading stuff here
    mEditBoxString = "Load Complete";
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Afterwards your dialog will show **Load Complete** in the edit box.

Comment: Ok so basically I have to call Update data in the view? Also can you show me an example of accessing the editboxstring in the view?

Comment: You never have to worry about to view. You update **mEditBoxString** and do **UpdateData(FALSE)** and the view takes care of itself

Comment: Ok basically the dialog box asks for number of rows and number of columns. Those rows and columns are using the view to generate a grid of rectangles. I have the code set up for that I just need to get the rows and columns values from the other dialog. How can I use mEditBoxString in the view?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you don't understand how to hook up OnLoadClicked to a button, I would recommend you do a **MFC** tutorial or read a book on it

Comment: If your view **ViewA** is popping up **DialogB**. Make mEditBoxString member of your view. Pass its reference or address to **DialogB** and  hook up the binding. In your **DialogB::OnOk** call **UpdateData(FALSE)**. This way once your dialog is dismissed **View** will contain all the needed values